# How to create verified account during meteor seed

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have to create a verified account on seeding. The below user object creates `user.email[0].verified = 'false'` But it should be in `true`.

```
user = {
  name: 'Admin',
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: 'password',
}
Meteor.startup(function() {
 if (Meteor.users.find().count() < 2) {
      Accounts.createUser(user); // It create user verification as false. How to make them true
 }
});
```

I tried the below object but no use.

```
user = {
  name: 'Admin',
  email: [address:'admin@example.com',verified:true],
  password: 'password',
}
```

Meteor packages:

```
accounts-password
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Accounts.addEmail allows to programatically set the *verified* property. According to the documentation it should overwrite these settings if the user already has that email registered. Worth giving it a try

```
Accounts.addEmail(userId, newEmail, [verified])
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-addEmail

In your case (on the server):

```
user = {
  name: 'Admin',
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: 'password',
}
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.users.find().count() < 2) {
    userId = Accounts.createUser(user);
    Accounts.addEmail(userId, user.email, true);
  }
});
```